# What's the dedicate way to use ExecutorService and Future?

Tags: java, future, executorservice

I have a batch of items. And for each item, I can get the itemID, then use this ID to do some DB lookup and generate all the transactions for this batch.

```
List<BatchItem> batchItemsList; // assume this list already have a list of items       
List<Transaction> results = new ArrayList<>();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
List<Future<Transaction>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

for(BatchItem item: batchItemsList) {
    MyThread worker = new MyThread(item);
    Future<Transaction> future = executor.submit(worker);
    tasks.add(future);
}

for(Future<Transaction> t: tasks) {
       results.add(t.get());
}
```

MyThread.java

```
public class MyThread implements Callable<Transaction>{
  private final BatchItem batchItem;

  public MyThread(BatchItem batchItem) {
    this.batchItem = batchItem;
  }

  @Override
  public Transaction call() throws Exception {
    String id = batchItem.getId();
    // SQL lookups....
    Transaction t = new Transaction(sql lookup result values...);
    return t;
  }
}
```

**Question 1:**
Do I really need to create all the MyThread object? If I have 15k items, that means I'll create 15k MyThread objects in the memory... What's the dedicate way to solve the problem?

**Question 2**
Do I need to check if the Future is done? If so, how should I handle isdone()?

Comment: 15k `MyThread` objects do not take up that much space.  15K objects that small?  100% okay.  (It wouldn't be if they were actually `Thread`s, but they aren't.)

Comment: Your `ExecutorService` is fixed at 5. That means only 5 `MyThread` objects can be processed at a time. If 5 tasks are being processed, the 6th task must wait for a task to finish. When one of the 5 tasks finishes, the object containing the finished task should be garbage. So unless you are maintaining references to every task created? there's a very low chance of all 15k being in heap at once before GC kicks in.

Comment: Depends on the situation, you didn't give enough context. `Future#get` blocks the thread until the task is finished, so if you don't want to block the thread, you should do `if(future.isDone()) results.add(t.get())` to make sure a value is ready. This is usually done in applications that execute a loop at a specific frame-rate or as fast as possible, and can't let `get` block the loop's execution. You really shouldn't be asking 2 questions in 1 post. Next time, create a follow up questions if you have more than one question, but make sure they haven't been asked & answered already.

Comment: ok, I got it. For Question1:  the number of object is depend on the size of ExecutorService not the size of the for loop. For Question 2: Future.get() will block until the result returns. Do I need to add isDone() check?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Thanks for the tips!

Comment: "*the number of object is depend on the size of ExecutorService not the size of the for loop*" - only in this situation, not all. How many objects exist in heap memory depends on much more than what you see. You shouldn't focus on it unless it becomes an issue. Once it's an issue, you should profiler (VisualVM, Java Mission Control, etc..) to see what is consuming the most memory. Otherwise, the GC will take care of your heap by removing dead objects when needed. The worst thing you can do is waste time optimizing code which you don't know is problematic. You should always use a profiler.